# SVN Error: Generate file in unified diff format was failed svn: E125007

Tags: eclipse, svn, svnkit

I am using Eclipse Juno (4.2.1) with SVN Kit 1.7.5.v1, Subversion SVN connection 3.0.0.20121013-170. I've checkout of my trunk and I want to compare (diff) with my branch, so that I can review my code changes. however, each time I try to generate, it fails with following error :

```
Generate file in unified diff format was failed. svn: E125007: Path
'/home/user2/projects/Trunk-2   (.../home/user2/projects/Trunk-2)'
must be an immediate child of the directory
'/home/user2/projects/Trunk-2   (.../home/user2/projects/Trunk-2)'
```

I've tried to generate diff from command line as well, still same error. Actually diff is generated but it's not proper unidiff and tools such as Jira Crucible do not accept the diff file.

Any idea why I might be facing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be bug with Jira FishEye+Crucible, however, I've resolved the issue with a workaround. 
Resolved the issue by:

- Delete property change  lines such as :

  Property changes on: /Validator.class.php

  ---

  Deleted: svn:mergeinfo

  Reverse-merged /Validator.class.php:r8387-8842

  Reverse-merged /Validator.class.php:r8746-8979

  Reverse-merged /Validator.class.php:r8860-8862
- FishEye+Crucible seems to have some issue with property changes and merge info in Diff/Path files, so it's better to remove them.
- Optionally add **\ No newline at end of file** at the end of the file.

Doing above have resolved problems for me, I hope this to be useful for someone facing same problem.

Cheers

Ravish